# Why is the header missing from a taxonomy view?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two views the first was created with no page or block and all defaults for "show" were kept. I have a header on that view and it shows fine.

The other view was created with no page or block but show was changed from "content" to "taxonomy" and I selected my vocabulary from the next option box. I have a similar header to this view (both use a panel pane) but the header for the taxonomy doesn't show. If I add a footer it will output fine but the header never renders on the page. Is there a known issue for headers and a taxonomy view?

Comment: May I know what that header returns? Did you use inspect element to see whether the header is printed in that page?

Comment: Yes, I inspected the page. the view normally returns three containers: views-header, views-container, views-footer (when a header and footer is present). This view  doesn't return the header.

Comment: views-header container is empty?